# My $.extend does not seem to work when inside a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
File 1:
$(document).ready(function () {
   addDataTableExts();
}

File 2:
function addDataTableExts() {
   $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
        sWrapper: 'no-margin last-child'
   }
}
```

This seems to work okay. I now tried to replace this with the following:

```
File 2:
(function () {

    $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
        sWrapper: 'no-margin last-child'
    }
}
```

This doesn't work.

Is there some reason why it only seems to work if I do this the first way? I thought
that by changing the first line of File 2 then it would cause the code to get 
executed without me calling it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks it's just an error with my formatting of the question. Sorry about that. I will fix it.

Comment: Do you plan to fix it any time soon? Correctly showing the thing that isn't working is *kind of important to the question*.

Comment: Did you just forgot to post the closing `)();` in file 2 or is that the source of your error?

Comment: @Bergi: Her comment above is in reply to my comment asking exactly that seconds after the question was posted. I guess I shouldn't have deleted it when she replied, until she'd actually done it, because here we are well over 10 minutes later and she hasn't bothered to correct it. To my mind, this is "Not a real question" and a waste of people's time until/unless she actually posts the (correct) code that isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed the code from running in the `ready` event to running immediately. It seems that you are loading your datatable plugin after loading file 2, so the plugin doesn't exist yet when you try to use it.

If you put it back in the `ready` event, it should work:

```
File 2:
$(document).ready(function () {

  $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
    sWrapper: 'no-margin last-child'
  }

});
```

Note: Events in jQuery are not exclusive, so you can have several `ready` event handlers in the same page without problems.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason to wait to run the database code at document ready, does there? I would suggest just ordering the scripts so the database plugin is loaded before File 2. No reason to postpone JS that can be run before the ready event, IMHO.

Comment: @AHM: That is a good point. I wanted to show what the difference was between the codes, and how to make it work the same with a minimal change, but if it is possible to rearrange the loading so that the plugin is loaded earlier, then that would of course be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I thought that by changing the first line of File 2 then it would cause the code to get executed without me calling it."*

If you actually changed *only* the first line as shown then you've created a syntax error - you've added an opening `(` without a closing `)`. But simply adding the closing `)` won't cause the now anonymous function expression to be executed. If you want the code to get executed without being called from File 1 you need to add extra parentheses `()` on the end to actually invoke the function.

Also you had a missing closing `)` after the `}` at the end of `$.extend(...`, though that was also a problem in the first version of your code (and also a problem with the document ready handler in File 1).

```
(function () {
    $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
        sWrapper: 'no-margin last-child'
    });    // <-- add missing ); here
})();      // <-- add missing )(); here
```

But you don't need the containing function at all unless it also wraps other code that you don't show, because that $.extend() statement on its on doesn't have any deleterious effect on the global scope.

Finally, if you do need to run that `$.extend()` after the page is ready but don't want to have a dependency between your two files you can add a document ready handler directly in File 2. Multiple document ready handlers will all be executed.